# Convert object or array into JSON without column names

Tags: vb.net

I need to convert a VB.Net array into a JSON but without column names, I have this:

[image]

Then with this code, I serialize that:

```
 Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
 Dim t As String = serializer.Serialize(filas)
```

But the result is all together like this:

`[""430"",""482"",""12"",""7"",""458"",""602"",""12"",""11"",""490"",""510"",""5"",""44"",""400"",""471"",""4"",""4"",""455"",""514"",""7"",""9"",""514"",""588"",""3"",""9"",""494"",""556"",""10"",""8"",""385"",""551"",""2"",""19"",""434"",""647"",""11"",""9"",""423"",""633"",""11"",""17"",""379"",""516"",""7"",""14"",null,null,null,null]`

And I need it like this:

`[["2018-1", 400, 450, 10,5], ["2018-2", 300, 350, 15, 10], ["2018-3", 500, 400, 20, 15]]`

How can I obtain the JSON like that?

Comment: Can you please explain the pattern of your desired JSON and also the dataType of your variables "filas"

Comment: You need a class with apparently a Date and 4 values to get that output. Then an array or List of them.  JSON is just the text representation of a specific object - the output will reflect the structure of the item being serialized.

Answer (score 0):

For example you could do with with List.

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of String) From {"1", "2"}
Dim list2 As New List(Of String) From {"3", "4"}
Dim JSONList As New List(Of List(Of String)) From {list1, list2}
Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim t As String = serializer.Serialize(JSONList)
'[["1","2"],["3","4"]]
```

Or your array and object.

```
Dim list1 As String() = {"1", "2"}
Dim list2 As String() = {"3", "4"}
Dim JSONList As Object = {list1, list2}
Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim t As String = serializer.Serialize(JSONList)
'[["1","2"],["3","4"]]
```

Comment: In your last example you're creating a [jagged array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/#jagged-arrays), so instead of an `Object` you can declare like so: `Dim JSONList As String()()`. It's the array equivalent of your first example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help I ended doing with a for like this

```
For iOuter As Integer = filas.GetLowerBound(0) To filas.GetUpperBound(0)
        'iOuter represents the first dimension
        For iInner As Integer = filas.GetLowerBound(1) To filas.GetUpperBound(1)
            'iInner represents the second dimension
            'filas(iOuter, iInner) = "This Isn't Nothing" 'Set the value

            If iInner = 0 Then
                cadenaJson = cadenaJson + result3(iOuter).ToString() + ","
            End If

            If iInner < filas.GetUpperBound(1) Then
                cadenaJson = cadenaJson + filas(iOuter, iInner).ToString + ","
            Else
                cadenaJson = cadenaJson + filas(iOuter, iInner).ToString
            End If

        Next 'iInner
        If iOuter = filas.GetUpperBound(0) Then
            cadenaJson = cadenaJson + "]]"
            'cadenaJson = cadenaJson + " "
        Else
            cadenaJson = cadenaJson + "],["
            'cadenaJson = cadenaJson + ","
        End If
        'If you are only interested in the first element you don't need the inner loop
        'filas(iOuter, 0) = "This is the first element in the second dimension"
    Next 'iOuter
```